# Haman Hanged on Branch of Eitz HaDaas?

Tags: midrash, purim, megillat-esther, haman

Rav Eytan Feiner mentioned in a [shiur](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=78926) that the tree used to hang Haman was the Eitz HaDaas, based on a Midrash. Where is this Midrash located? (I found [Esther Rabba 9:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther_Rabbah.9.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which discusses it, but can't find the precise mention of what Rav Feiner was saying.)

Comment: In the _shi'ur_ he is quoting the _Da'as Z'kenim_ [on _B'reshis_ 3:11](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02513.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L2). Check out the annotated English translation thereof [on Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daat_Zkenim_on_Genesis.3.11.1?lang=en&with=About&lang2=en). It is attributed (I think) to דעת זקנים, בתרגום רבי אליהו מונק, and says that the target _midrash_ is unfound.

Comment: Isn’t there a Midrash that it was from the Teivah?

Comment: @Donielf Midrash Abba Gorion and Yalkut Shimoni are the source for that.

Answer (score 0):

In this sefer, Targum Simcha Tu B'Shvat the connection is made between Haman and the Eitz Hadas, suggesting that the gallows were from the original Eitz Hadas.

[image: Targum Simcha Tu B'Shvat]